# Can I create a dll/library in MONO to be used in a C++ program under Linux?

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I think the title explains everything; is this possible? Develop a ClassLibrary project to be used in a C++ linux project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look here for detailed documentation: http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono